# Quelle est la langue principale du site? What is the primary language of the site?

Tags: discussion, language

Une décision que nous devons prendre dans les prochains jours est la langue principale du site. Il y a des choses qui peuvent être bilingues (en particulier on peut avoir des questions en anglais et des questions en français — c'est ce qui était prévu sur [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29480?phase=definition)). Mais l'environnement dominant sera quand même dans une langue.

- Un participant doit-il forcement comprendre l'anglais ? (Pour l'instant oui, l'interface et la FAQ sont en anglais, mais c'est un obstacle facile à surmonter.)
- Un participant doit-il forcément comprendre le français ?
- Les étiquettes (tags), notamment, seront-elles en anglais ou en français ?
- Le site meta est-il anglophone ou bilingue ? (Pour l'instant, il ne peut pas être que francophone, lorsqu'il s'agit de communiquer avec les développeurs.)

---

A decision that we need to take in the next few days is the principal language of the site. Some things can be bilingual, in particular we can allow both English-language and French-language questions (this was the plan on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29480?phase=definition)). But there will inevitably be a dominant language.

- Must every participant understand English? (For the time being, yes, because the interface and the FAQ are in English, but this can be remedied easily.)
- Must every participant understand French?
- In particular, should the tags be in English or in French?
- Is the Meta site English-speaking or bilingual? (It cannot be French-only at the moment, because we need to communicate with the developers in English.)

Comment: Apparement c'est bien parti pour rester en Francais. Une telle decision venant de personnes naturellement francophones semble un peu egoiste cependant... C'est dommage, ce site aurait pu aider des amis qui cherchent a apprendre le francais et ont souvent des questions, je ne vais probablement pas leur recommander ce site car leur Francais n'est pas encore assez bon... Certes l'anglais reste accepte mais ca limite l'utilisation dans le temps, c'est pas rentable de passer son temps ici quand on voit que 90% des questions/reponses sont en Francais: mettez completement le site en francais...

Comment: @Aki The proportion is more like 50%, and askers who use English are not made to feel unwelcome.

Comment: Oh really? Well I admit I didn't really check, it just felt like 90%. My other point is that people want to learn from others' questions, which is not possible if they can't understand the question being asked. So this site mainly targets readers who can already understand French, which is not the majority IMHO.

Comment: @Aki The people who would most benefit from this site are people who already have some level of French proficiency. If you're just beginning to learn French, you need closer tutoring than a Q&A site can provide. A majority of the regulars on the site are native French speakers. Posts in English exclude the people who know the subject matter (French) but don't speak your proposed metalanguage (English).

Comment: A stack app focused on translating stack exchanges would be fricking awesome. If I could code with any proficiency, I would do it, but as it is I would botch it horribly (babel fish, anyone?). Plus, the coder (or a large number of helpers) would need to know these other languages. Just an idea, but I thought I'd put in my two cents (on an old question). [My situation is that I have taken two-three years of French in school so far, but I am nowhere near close to ability to easily translate such large amounts of text as would be required for reading here, if a question wasnt answered in English]

Comment: @TheUgly Automatic translation doesn't really work. It's improving, but reliable automatic translation is still science fiction. Automatic translation can usually tell you what a text is about, but not what it's saying — missing a negation here and there might be good in percentage of terms of words correctly translated, but it's catastrophic in terms of usefulness.

Answer (score 28):

**La langue principale du site devrait être le français**, et la plupart des questions et des réponses sur le site devraient être en français, puisque les experts sur le thème du site (qui est, rappelons-le, le français) maîtrisent par définition le français mais ne sont pas forcément capables de comprendre ou de s'exprimer en anglais. Il vaut mieux que les débutants posent leurs questions en français ([quitte à ce qu'un passant les corrige](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/policy-on-correcting-peoples-french)), plutôt que de poser des questions en anglais qui risquent de ne pas être comprises. De plus une trop large proportion de questions dans une langue autre que le français ferait fuire de nombreux francophones. Encore une fois, il ne faut pas repousser les experts.

Il y a quelques types de questions pour lesquelles l'anglais se défend :

- Des questions qui demandent spéciquement des explications sur une nuance du français que n'a pas l'anglais. Exemple : [When to use connaître and when to use savoir?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/39/connaitre-and-savoir) ; si cette question est intéressante et pas si élémentaire, c'est parce qu'elle demande plus qu'une simple lecture des articles *connaître* et *savoir* dans un dictionnaire — le fait que les deux mots sont en général traduits par le même (*know*) en anglais est pertinent.
- Des questions de [traduction](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/translation-questions) entre l'anglais et le français.

(Méta est une autre histoire. Vous pouvez constater que pour le moment j'essaire d'y poster systématiquement dans les deux langues, afin d'être compris à la fois des francophones et du personnel de Stack Exchange.)

---

**The primary language of the site should be French**, and most questions and answers on the site should be in French, since the experts on the topic of the site (the French language) are by definition fluent in French and may not be able to understand or write in English. It is better for learners to post in halting but comprehensible French ([and have their question improved](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/policy-on-correcting-peoples-french)) than to post in English only to have their question misunderstood. Furthermore a large proportion of questions that are not in French would drive away many native French speakers. Again, we don't want to drive the experts away.

There are a few questions that might fare better in English:

- Questions that are specifically aimed at explaining nuances of French with respect to English. Example: [When to use connaître and when to use savoir?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/39/connaitre-and-savoir); part of the reason why this question is not so easy (and why I don't think it's a general reference question) is that there's more to it than the dictionary definitions — the fact that *connaître* and *savoir* are usually translated as the same word (“know”) in English is relevant.
- Questions asking for [translations](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/translation-questions) to and from English.

(Meta is a different matter. As you can see, so far I'm trying to keep my posts on Meta bilingual, so that they can be understood by both the Francophone denizens of the site and Stack Exchange personnel.)

Comment: Alors, pas encore corrigé le Français de Ninefingers? :)

Comment: @Benjol Je comprends bien le système "stackexchange" alors si quelqu'un a amélioré mon français, je sais comment trouver la différence et alors je peux apprendre, mais ce n'est pas vrai pour tous nos membres, dont les nouveaux utilisateurs bénéficierait plus peut-être par un commentaire. À moi, c'est autant.

Comment: @Ninefingers On other sites, improving the English in a post is considered routine, so improving the French should be routine here anyway.

Comment: **La langue principale du site devrait être le français** : c'est vrai, mais le reste du site est en anglais (liens, profils, administration, architecture générale). Est-il techniquement possible de le traduire ?

Comment: @Stamm Il y a une traduction non officielle et incomplète de l'interface pour les gens qui sont près à installer un userscript : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105169/help-translate-the-stack-exchange-ui-unofficial/105751#105751 Les bêta-testeurs sont bienvenus. Traduire la FAQ (qui est plutôt un guide d'utilisation) est sur ma liste de choses à faire (mais si quelqu'un d'autre est volontaire, très bien).

Comment: Lorsque je vois apparaître dans la partie "what's hot" de l'interface des questions sur la langue espagnole ou japonaise, il m'arrive, par curiosité, d'aller les consulter. Je ne parle pas ces langues, mais l'utilisation de l'anglais (lingua franca du monde, qu'on le veuille ou non !) me permet d'en prendre connaissance. À mon humble avis, des questions en français réduisent la facilité d'accès globale au site.

Comment: @Rémi Les “hot questions” sont filtrées : une question dont le titre n'a pas l'air d'être en anglais n'apparaîtra pas. C'est logique : le public est anglophone, on ne lui montre donc que des questions qu'il a une chance de comprendre. Les questions en français réduisent la facilité d'accès **aux anglophones**, mais les anglophones, pour la plupart, ne s'intéressent pas au français de toute façon. À contrario, les questions en français sont plus faciles d'accès pour les francophones, qui sont plus susceptibles d'être intéressés.

Comment: À propos des apprentis, j'ai lu précédemment une suggestion d'un site séparé « French learners » (comme pour [l'anglais](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)). Cela demande réflexion (risque de division trop importante de l'attention, gestion complexifiée) mais la piste vaut la peine d'être explorée. Il n'y aurait alors aucun doute que FR devrait être en français.

Comment: @Chop Aujourd'hui [french.se] est plutôt un French learners. Une minorité de questions posées par des francophones. Donc s'il y avait un nouveau site, ce serait plutôt un Français.SE, francophone (comme il y a maintenant [rus.se] et que [russian.se] a été déclaré pour apprenants post-facto). L'inconvénient de séparer comme ça, c'est que c'est très décevant pour la majorité des répondeurs actifs qui ont fait beaucoup d'efforts pour que ce site soit intéressant pour les locuteurs natifs. En fait, s'il y avait deux sites, il faudrait plutôt scinder le site existant en gardant les contributeurs.

Comment: @Gilles Effectivement, le français.SE serait pertinent. Quant à scinder le site, je pensais effectivement qu'il fallait conserver les contributeurs, mais il est vrai que l'on peut envisager une migration des questions pertinentes.

Comment: @Stamm L'[exemple donné par Gilles](http://rus.stackexchange.com/) te montre un exemple d'interface traduite. C'est une base en informatique.

Comment: @Gilles : je veux bien essayer de regarder la FAQ quand j'aurai cinq minutes. Tu me contactes sur un canal plus adapté pour discuter de comment s'organiser au mieux ?

Comment: @Chop On peut utiliser le [salon de clavardage](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1098/chez-cosette) (enfin le chat quoi). En général je suis logué en permanence mais dispo seulement en soirée.

Answer (score 15):

Good question.

For the record (and no offence, but,) I'm totally against asking questions in both languages at once.

I think the dominant language will happen naturally and depend on user-base. Any attempt to work against that is futile, I'd say.

Tags however, is a *VERY* good question, and I don't have any answer. I think they should *definitely* be monolingual, and I'd be *tempted* to say that they should be in French (this is FL&U after all!).

Brainwave: using synonyms to translate from English into French!

We will always need to communicate with developers, but I think there are enough of us here to translate for them if need be.

**UPDATE**: my take on this is refining slightly: I would say that the *only* reason for asking questions in English (on main) is because the asker isn't comfortable writing it in French. Autrement dit: I'm think I'm *against* francophones asking questions in English.

Comment: On [german.se], tags are in English. I don't think we should do this, because the proportion of native French speakers who also know enough English to keep up with and be interested in an English-speaking site is far smaller.

Comment: OK, so we're agreeing. I think using tag synonyms to translate English tags directly into their French equivalents is an elegant solution which would avoid tripping up English users.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'tag synonyms'; do you mean just adding 2 tags (one in each language) instead of 1?

Comment: @Jez Yes: you type the English name, and it's silently translated to the French name. The software already has that feature, all we'd need to do is enter the list of names we want to translate.

Comment: @Jez SE sites allow us to make one tag essentially redirect to another.  So any time someone tags a question `grammar` it would automatically change that to `la grammaire`, etc.

Comment: ... hmmm. Whether or not to use the article in tag names is an interesting question.  French is a lot more particular about article usage than English.

Comment: @keithjgrant, that deserves [it's own question!](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/81/should-tags-include-the-definite-article) :)

Answer (score 8):

Je suis en accord avec @Gilles - la langue du site doit etre francais; facilement car c'est fou du demanderais en anglais quand les meilleurs (quantite et qualite) du renseignements sont les francais qui ne peut pas etre bilingue.

Je suggère que nous permettons à des questions pour être affichées en français ou en anglais et en français, avec la partie anglaise étant facultative et seulement pour clarifier les corrections pour eux avec  mauvais français

---

I agree with Gilles - the site language must be French - simply because it's madness to ask in  English when the best quantity and quality of answers will be posted by those who can read French as well or better than they can read English.

I would also suggest that we allow questions to be posted in French, or in French (and underneath) in English - to clarify the meaning for those of us with not very good french skills.

Answer (score 7):

Je suis Britannique. Quand j'étais à l'école, tous les professeurs faisaient cours en anglais, en dépit de ce que la plupart parlaient français couramment, s'ils n'étaient pas bilingues voire de langue maternelle française. Comment peut-on s’améliorer si l'on n'a pas la chance de pouvoir utiliser la langue ? S'il y a un choix à faire, je soutiens le français.

However:

1. As Benjol says, it's a community decision.
2. Having another language to compare/contrast with is useful. For English learners of French, comparing our own language helps sometimes. So I don't support a total exclusion of other languages.
3. However, this is about French. Allowing a majority contribution in English unfairly disadvantages say German students of French, for example. So half of this answer may be unintelligible to some of our visitors.
4. Obviously the UI is in English. I [did start an effort to fix this](https://stackapps.com/questions/2392/stack-overflow-ui-translation-via-greasemonkey) (you need GreaseMonkey) but unfortunately becoming employed put paid to my efforts at the time. Please don't laugh at my bad French - has been a while. [Anyone wishing to help me continue/improve this work - please do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105169/help-translate-the-stackexchange-ui-unofficial). Clearly, a better solution would be UI translation for sites like this.

A hard question, I feel, but overall, I am in favour of being in French.

Comment: Despite what I said [here](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/3/policy-on-correcting-peoples-french), anybody who dares to laugh at anybody else's 'bad' French or English here will be summarily executed. A guillotine would be fitting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your UI translation effort! I'm going to have a look (when I have time… not always easy, in spite of what you may think from my SE activity). Warning: I don't know computer vocabulary in French.

Comment: @Gilles It might be slightly broken - it depends what SE Inc do with their markup on each page as I'm using jQuery to identify the elements and change their contents. Last time I tried it it broke the user pages, but translated the home page ok. Likewise; my free time is fairly restricted, but if we can put together a working template, that's less work for Jeff and team to do when it comes to working on the actual translation effort.

Comment: @Ninefingers I know nothing about web programming. I was proposing to look at the translations, I'll leave the programmy bits to others. BTW, have you marketed this to other languages, e.g. [german.se]?

Comment: @Gilles not yet - I don't speak German (my French is rusty enough, as I have discovered in the past two weeks!) but I was thinking if we could get help from [Pekka](http://stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka) we might really get something going. Start a chat room is perhaps the best way?

Answer (score 3):

To answer this question, we have to address a deeper question: who is this site's audience? There are a few possible answers to that question:

1. Francophones looking to better their French.
2. Anglophones learning French.
3. Anglophones learning French and francophones learning English.

If the answer is #1, then we should go with French. If the answer is #2, then we should go with English. Finally, if the answer is #3, then we can go either way or declare both of equal value.

If the site was meant for francophones, then English wouldn't even be allowed. After all, it would be for people with an already decent grasp of French. The fact that we allow another language other than French clearly implies that those people are also part of the audience. Since option #1 doesn't account for why we allow English in here, that can't be the answer.

That leaves option #2 and #3. Which of the two is it?

The truth is, that question has already been implicitly answered [in an other meta question](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/translation-questions):

> Do not allow questions asking for translations from French into English as such; however, it is fine to ask for an explanation in English of what a difficult French sentence means.

Unless we decide to revise that policy (it's fairly new, after all), the answer is #2. The fact that we do not allow French to English translation makes it clear that it is a site about French, not French and English - which is to be expect of *French.SE*. As a result, the answer cannot be #3 and thus it is #2.

Therefore, the primary language of this site should be English.

If the community doesn't like the answer to this question, then perhaps that suggests there is something wrong with the original intent/design of the site. But I don't see how, given the current policies, French should be this site's primary language. It wouldn't be consistent with the design.

Comment: I disagree with this policy. The site should be for *anyone* to better their French. I'm not keen on allowing English, but I'm prepared to deal with a moderate amount of it. If the site is primarily for Anglophones learning English, it won't interest me (or many other francophones) much.

Comment: @Gilles: I'm not keen on it either, but it's the logical conclusion to the other policies that have been adopted so far. As I said, if the community has a problem with English being the primary language, then it's sign of a deeper problem.

Comment: We have a deeper problem already? where?

Comment: @Gilles: I have not said that. I said that our current policies cater to anglophones learning French, so English should be our primary language. If the community does not want English to be our primary language, then that suggests there is something wrong with our other policies too.

Comment: @Borror0 How about 4. Anglophones learning French **and** francophones looking to improve their French and discuss the language?

Comment: @Jez: We can only dialogue in one language: either in French, which excludes anglophones whose French isn't that great yet, or in English, which excludes all the francophones whose English isn't that great. That's why option #4 is a lie. It doesn't really exist.

Comment: I don't agree.  Some people can dialogue in one language, others in another.

Comment: As Gilles knows, I disagree with the French policy. My argument is concerning one other language website: japanese stack exchange. There should be some kind of uniformity and logic within stackexchange. Moreover, people learning one language may not master it at a sufficient level to learn from all questions/answers if they are in French. I often find my self digging through questions in the japanese site and without English it would be hopeless and I wouldn't learn or contribute at all. Please consider that most people in the world who study french aren't french, help them learn.

Comment: @Aki We certainly don't help people to learn french by not using french (except during their first year of learning, but then they probably don't have to use SE anyway, as their teacher can answer their question in their native language, (which often isn't english either))

Answer (score 2):

A mon avis, la langue principale du site devrait être **en français**, avec des exceptions dans les cas suivants:

- La personne qui pose la question n'a pas encore débuté ou vient de débuter son apprentissage de la langue française, dans ce cas elle est authorisée à poser sa quesion en anglais
- Linguistes ne connaîsant pas le français mais qui désirent la comparer avec d'autres langues quand à ses caractéristiques (examples de questions : combien de temps verbaux il y a en français, combien de consonnes différentes, quelle proportion du vocabulaire vient du grec, etc...)

Dans ces cas, la question et les réponses devraient être uniquement en anglais, sans français.

A mon avis il est douteux, voire fâcheux, que certains membres de "french SE" gagnent des points de réputations juste en traduisant des posts pour les rendre bilingues. La discussion devrait se faire soit entièrement en français (dans la majorité des cas), soit entièrement en anglais (dans les deux cas pré-cités), afin d'être la moins confuse possible. Il n'y a aucune nécessité de vouloir tout traduire les questions et les réponses qui ont été faites dans une langue dans l'autre.

Le pire de tout est sans aucun doute celles qui mélangent les deux langues au sein de la même phrase, comme par exemple [celle-ci](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13718/how-are-il-faut-and-we-related), [celle-ci](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7407/when-to-use-je-te-kiffe)

Il est très difficile de comprendre ces questions (et les réponses qui vont avec) car elles insérent des mots de français au milieu de l'anglais ce qui est confusant et difficile à comprendre, même pour ceux qui ont une maîtrise des deux langues.

**Si les personnes qui posent les quesions utilisent quelques mots de français, alors c'est une bonne indication que la question (et les réponses) doivent être entièrement en français.**

Il est désolant de voir des gens qui prétent apprendre le français mais qui refusent de faire l'effort de poser une question entièrement en français (peu importe à quel point il est correct).

Answer (score 1):

Je ne suis pas d'accord avec l’idée que le site doit être principalement dans une langue ou une autre, ou plutôt, que nous mêmes posons des règles quand a cela. Je trouve que c'est un effort inutile et une mauvaise idée.

- Le choix entre l'anglais et le français est un faux dilemme selon moi, le site doit être accommodant pour les francophiles, qu'importe la langue maternelle de l'utilisateur. Dans notre cas aujourd'hui, il y a beaucoup d'anglophones parce que le réseau est parti des EU et parce que c'est un dénominateur commun sur internet en général.
- Imposer des règles peut décourager certains de participer. Différentes personnes apprennent de différentes manières, et il y a des francophones de niveaux variés sur le site. Si quelqu'un estime qu'il a besoin de s'appuyer sur l'anglais ou plutôt qu'il veut faire l'effort de s'exprimer en français c'est son choix, pourquoi lui imposer notre avis ? S'exprimer dans une langue étrangère avec des inconnus sur internet est peut être assez intimidant pour certains, pourquoi ajouter encore une barrière ?
- En règle générale je trouve qu'on peut pas imposer des règles mais plutôt d'encourager un comportement. On peut très bien demander que les gens s'expriment seulement en français, ça n’empêche pas de poser des questions en anglais. Au contraire, quand il y a une contrainte les gens trouveront toujours un moyen de la contourner. Ce genre de choses s'impose naturellement au fil du temps avec l'usage, essayer d'aller contre ça ne mène a rien. On peut par contre encourager l'usage du français.
- Le dernier point est une opinion personnelle, je ne vois pas en quoi ça gêne d'avoir du contenu bi- ou même multilingue sur le site. D'autres sites comme le Russe, le Japonais ou l'Espagnol ont aussi beaucoup de contenu anglais.