# Shouldn't this website be in English?

Tags: discussion, language

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quelle est la langue principale du site? What is the primary language of the site?](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/quelle-est-la-langue-principale-du-site-what-is-the-primary-language-of-the-sit)

Off-topic but I think this is really a problem.

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/ Is not in Japanese, and it really helps everyone.

I can't learn if I can't understand a question. So everyone should post and answer in English. I hope moderators can enforce this in a not-so-distant future.

Regards.

Comment: By using English, you exclude people who do not speak English! We debated this in the early days of the site, and concluded that both French and English are accepted. Since this site is for “linguists, teachers, students, and anyone interested in the finer points of the French language”, it is expected that most visitors understand some French anyway. Nonetheless, you may ask and answer questions in English if you aren't comfortable with posting in French.

Comment: By the way, questions about a Stack Exchange site belong on the corresponding [meta site](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/faq). I've migrated your question to its proper place.

Comment: Then why is Japanese stackexchange not mainly in Japanese? It would be terrible this way. It's not different for French. Indeed the description tends to emphasize "finer points of the French language", but in the end people will still want to think it's the french equivalent of the japanese stack exchange. I speak french and I know most french speak english, as most people in the world. They could speak english for their explanation while providing french sentences as examples.

Comment: I can't speak for other language sites, you'd have to ask on their metas. As I wrote, we had this debate (feel free to add your voice to the relevant meta posts), and decided to allow both languages. It's quite natural to have a site in French since Stack Exchange sites are primarily targeted at experts and experts in French tend to speak French better than English.