# 1000 jours en béta: voyons les chiffres

Tags: discussion, beta-phase

Dans quelques jours, ce site atteindra le jour 1000 en phase béta. À quel point cette communauté est-elle vivante? Je viens tout juste de débarquer et ce que je vois sur [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29480/french-language) m'indique qu'il y a du travail à faire, notamment au niveau des questions posées par jour (2.9, alors qu'on en voudrait au moins une quinzaine).

Voyons l'historique de l'activité du site ([SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/french/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph#graph)):

[image: activity & voting since October 2011]

Au niveau de la distribution des privilèges et points de réputation des utilisateurs dits "avides" ([SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/french/query/160371/distribution-of-avid-users-by-reputation-tier)), les proportions sont bonnes, mais il faut clairement davantage d'utilisateurs:

[image: avid users distribution]

Au cours des 60 derniers jours (relatif à la dernière mise à jour des données sur SEDE), 884 utilisateurs se sont présentés sur le site, avec un score moyen de 308.6; parmis ceux-ci, 206 sont des utilisateurs dits "avides", et le score moyens de ceux-ci est de 1140.6 - les 884 utilisateurs totalisent 272,799 points de réputation, dont 86.13% est détenu par les utilisateurs dits "avides" ([source](http://data.stackexchange.com/french/query/174384/avid-users-rep-score-targets)).

Là où le bât blesse, c'est au niveau de la [répartition de la richesse](http://data.stackexchange.com/french/query/177002/how-rich-are-the-1-active-users): 1% des utilisateurs détiennent 17.2% des points de réputation.. mais ce 1% est constitué de.... 2 utilisateurs.

La [courbe de croissance](http://data.stackexchange.com/french/query/164480/reputation-races#graph) des points de réputation du top 5 des utilisateurs du site montre une croissance relativement constante, mais rien de spectaculaire - probablement dû au nombre peu élevé de questions sur le site.

---

Je ne suis membre que depuis à peine 36 heures, j'ai publié un commentaire, une réponse et cette question sur le site méta, et j'apparais déjà au 3e rang au niveau de la [méta-participation](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/users), derrière deux modérateurs. Quelque chose cloche...

---

En conclusion, il m'apparaît que ce site a besoin, avant d'accueillir de nouveaux utilisateurs en masse, de se construire une communauté. Soyez **actifs sur méta**, fréquentez la salle de **clavardage**, discutez des questions qui devraient être posées sur ce site, **posez-les** et répondez-y - travaillez les titres des questions, faites en sorte que ce site ait l'air vivant. 2-3 questions par jour est loin d'être suffisant, les questions n'arriveront pas d'elles-mêmes! C'est l'éternel problème de l'oeuf et de la poule...

---

> ***English readers***: this site needs more questions asked. If you're having problems reading anything in this post, please ask about it on the main site! (no kidding - of course if you have questions or comments about the content of this post, please comment or answer below!)

Comment: Un percentile qui “possède” 15-25% de points de réputation est apparemment très commun parmi les “gros” sites de SE.

Answer (score 12):

Je pense qu’un des problème de la communauté est que les personnes qui posent les questions ne sont pas celles qui y répondent. Parce que, tout simplement, l’essentiel des gens qui répondent aux questions sont francophones, ont une bonne maîtrise de la langue et ont a portée de main leur dico ou leur grammaire pour répondre aux questions qu’ils se posent encore. Et, quand une question survient et que leurs ouvrages de référence ne suffisent plus, on s’aperçoit que tout le monde possède les mêmes, et les réponses ne sont pas foison.

Or les personnes qui fréquentent longtemps French.SE sont, je pense, pour la plupart des « répondeurs<sup>1</sup> ». D’où peu de questions ; peu d’attrait ; peu d’activité sur le méta.

Alors certes, je partage ton avis, les habitués devraient poser plus de questions. Mais voilà : personnellement, je sèche un peu.

Et je ne vois pas trop comment faire avancer le schmilblick. Il serait probablement intéressant d’arriver à intéresser des linguistes et de tirer le site vers la littérature.

Si l’on veut attirer plus d’apprenants, peut-être rendre plus clair le fait que les questions en anglais sont les bienvenues également ?

---

1. Le terme m’amuse, mais toute suggestion plus heureuse est la bienvenue.

Comment: Un des solutions pour avoir plus de questions est que les répondeurs postent les question qu'il se posent avec la réponse qu'ils ont trouvé d'eux-même. C'est une pratique encouragé sur StackExchange et un bon moyen de générer du contenu de qualité.

Comment: Je l’ai fait ailleurs, mais bizarrement, je n’ai jamais pratiqué ici. Je tâcherai d’y songer la prochaine fois.

Answer (score 8):

Les statistiques sur Area 51 ne valent pas grand-chose. Ce sont les mêmes chiffres qui sont affichés depuis le tout début, alors qu'on n'avait aucune idée de ce qui fait la réussite d'un site. Depuis, on a des pistes, mais Area 51 affiche toujours les mêmes choses.

Les critères de succès d'un site restent assez flous, mais il y a quand même quelques pistes :

- Qualité : il faut que les questions aient des réponses. Stack Exchange mesure les questions « *answered* », définies comme ayant au moins une réponse avec un score positif (les questions closes ne comptent pas). Pas de problème à ce niveau, quasiment toutes les questions ont une réponse avec un score positif (c'est le cas sur tous les sites de langue sur Stack Exchange — il est en général facile pour un locuteur natif d'écrire une réponse qui, si elle n'est pas forcément géniale, est au moins potable).
- Qualité : tous les trois mois, dix questions sont tirées au sort et évaluées par les participants volontaires. Voir [l'évaluation d'avril](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-evaluation) et [site-evaluation](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-evaluation). De ce point de vue, nous sommes en général plutôt satisfaits.
- Quantité : il faut qu'il y ait un minimum d'activité pour que les gens gardent l'habitude de visiter le site. De ce point de vue, nous n'avons pas de problème. Il y a un noyau d'habitués fidèles, et nous ne manquons pas de volontaires pour répondre, éditer, revoir, etc.
- Quantité : moins que le niveau absolu du traffic, ce qui compte est sa croissance. Et c'est le cas : nous sommes aujourd'hui à plus de 3 questions/jour, alors que nous étions plutôt autour de 1 question/jour il y a deux ans. Le nombre de messages, et encore plus le nombre de visites, montrent une croissance continue.

Le chiffre de 15 questions/jour sur Area 51 est arbitraire, et beaucoup de sites sont considérés comme ayant réussi (et sont passés au stade *graduated*) avec bien moins. Sur ce chiffre, *French Language* arrive même au niveau des sites matures les plus lents.

Sur la répartition de la richesse, les chiffres n'ont rien de surprenant ou d'inquiétant, l'ordre de grandeur est sensiblement le même ailleurs.

Pour la participation sur le site méta, comme le site a déjà plusieurs années et que la nature de la participation n'a pas sensiblement changé, il ne se passe pas grand-chose. Peu de gens posent des questions parce qu'il y a peu de questions à poser. C'est vrai qu'il y a peu de gens qui lisent aussi, mais ce n'est pas vraiment un problème tant qu'il ne se passe rien d'important.

Quant à ce qui est de poser des questions... C'est bien là que le bât blesse, et même si les chiffres sont satisfaisant, il reste encore beaucoup de chemin à faire. Les habitués sont en petit nombre n'ont pas de question tous les jours. Il faut donc du sang nouveau.

J'ai l'impression que la croissance vient surtout de questions de locuteurs non natifs. C'est assez naturel dans la mesure où le site est surtout visible par des anglophones : l'interface est en anglais, le reste du réseau Stack Exchange est en anglais. Le danger, c'est que ce site devienne un site de français langue étrangère — or beaucoup d'habitués ne sont pas là pour ça, donc il y a un risque que nous perdions nos meilleurs contributeurs. C'est pourquoi je pense que le salut du site ne passe que par la participation de plus de locuteurs natifs (professeurs et élèves du second et du troisième cycle, par exemple). Pour cela, une étape indispensable est une [interface en français](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/530/can-we-have-a-french-user-interface-peut-on-avoir-une-interface-en-francais).

Answer (score 5):

> En conclusion, il m'apparaît que ce site a besoin, avant d'accueillir de nouveaux utilisateurs en masse, de se construire une communauté. Soyez actifs sur méta, fréquentez la salle de clavardage, discutez des questions qui devraient être posées sur ce site, posez-les et répondez-y - travaillez les titres des questions, faites en sorte que ce site ait l'air vivant. 2-3 questions par jour est loin d'être suffisant, les questions n'arriveront pas d'elles-mêmes! C'est l'éternel problème de l'oeuf et de la poule...

A mon avis, cela ^^ est le truc le plus important.

(Pardonnez-moi si je continue en anglais, ou même franglais...) Alors. Building your community is the hardest part, but it's also the most important part of helping this community grow. It's what's going to keep your native speakers coming back even when there aren't many questions to answer, because they feel they have some ownership of this community, and like it's a place they belong to. Likewise, it is what will create an educational and friendly environment for French learners to come and ask questions.

If you are finding your site comprised mostly of questions from French learners and answers from native French speakers, that's okay! It might not be what you originally signed up for, but that's a community model that can work. Parleurs natifs (???) de français devraient visiter à [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com), où des gens qui apprennent l'anglais pose des questions et les autres qui parle l'anglais couramment (nativement, ou simplement étrangers doués) y répondent. Leur modèle sur ce site là marche très bien pour eux et ça peut marcher ici aussi facilement.

I like this site a lot, and I think it has a lot of potential for future growth. I used it as an example [pour les Italiens](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138/how-is-this-fledgling-site-doing). Keep plugging along. Stimulate your community in any way possible, both inexperienced askers and fluent answerers. Let me know if you have any ideas on where  community managers can step in and lend a hand. This is your site and your community. We're on hand to help, but for the most part, we leave it up to you guys to govern and to decide the future of your site. Alors: [foncez](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/673/comment-dit-on-have-at-it-en-francais)!

Comment: The problem with questions from learners, answers from natives is that because it isn't what some of us signed for, there's a risk of attrition. Furthermore, the more content we have in English, the less attractive the site becomes to French natives.

Comment: @Gilles I disagree. Having content in english actually makes me believe we can actually teach stuff to people who are *not* native speakers, which is what makes me want to come back here. Pardon my generalization, mais c'est vraiment chauvin de moins vouloir participer au site parce qu'il contient trop d'anglais au goût de l'utilisateur.