# De la pure littérature Française ou pas?

Tags: discussion, scope

Les questions ici sont-elles juste des questions en lien avec la langue française, ou peut-on aussi poser des questions à propos de programmation en français?

Je pose cette question, car j'ai vu qu'il n'y avait pas de StackOverflow en français, mais j'aimerais poser des questions sur Python à la communauté des programmeurs français et je voudrais savoir si ça ne dérange pas de le faire sur ce site.

Comment: Le réseau StackExchange étant divisé par  sujet et non par la langue parlée, le seul site qui y sert est SO. Mais il y en a des utilisateurs locuteurs de français et il y a Google Translate. C'est malheureusement la seule réponse que je saurais donner.

Comment: Merci @LukeSawczak mais je peut te dire que malheureusement il a des partie ou c'est divisé par langue et pas par sujet. Comme par exemple StackOverflow normal et le StackOverflow Portugais par exemple.

Comment: Ah j'ignorais cela. Ça me semble être exceptionnel. Merci de toute façon !

Comment: C'est moi qui vous remercie pour votre temps.

Comment: Il faut savoir que l'essentiel des programmeurs francophones sont obligés de travailler en anglais, indispensables pour comprendre le fonctionnement et obtenir des résultats sur internet, mais surtout beaucoup plus efficace qu'en français. et même si tu n'as pas forcément les moyen de poser des questions en anglais, utilise un traducteur et met ta question traduite (pas forcement parfaitement) sur le forum concerné, un éditeur comme moi réajustera le texte pour qu'il soit propre (et n'hésite pas à faire un dupliqua du texte en français en dessous au cas où un francophone du forum passe par là)

Comment: il faut savoir que les éditeurs préfèrent voir un texte en anglais pas parfait, plutôt qu'un autre dans une autre langue à devoir utiliser Google trad car ils ne peuvent être sûr du contenu initial de la question/réponse (c'est mon cas sur AskUbuntu si tu veux savoir)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non, ce site n'est pas fait pour répondre en français à des questions de programmation. Il existe dans certaines langues (russe, espagnol, portugais et japonais) mais pas en Français (ni dans aucune autre langue, d'ailleurs). En théorie, vous pouvez essayer d'en proposer sur https://area51.stackexchange.com, mais ça met du temps et il faut des supporters. Ceci étant dit, s'il n'existe pas déjà c'est qu'une partie de la communauté des programmeurs francophones se satisfait de la situation actuelle. **EDIT suite au commentaire de jlliagre**: il semble que les premières demandes aient été acceptées, mais qu'ensuite l'équipe SE aurait eu peur d'une démultiplication des sites (chaque thématique X chaque langue = beaucoup trop) et une dilution de la communauté. L'ajout de sites non anglophones est donc maintenant exclu, même si les sites non anglophones existants étaient sans doute trop gros pour être supprimés lorsque la décision a été prise. cfr [ici](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299682/why-is-there-no-french-stack-overflow) à propos de la création d'un SO en français.

Comme alternatives,

1) il y a Google translate et la possibilité de demander de l'aide pour bien exprimer votre problème sur le site d'[apprentissage de l'anglais](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

2) il existe des forums en français en dehors de stackOverflow pour des questions concernant Python (https://www.commentcamarche.net/forum/python-264 , https://www.developpez.net/forums/f96/autres-langages/python-zope/ )

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour la reponse

Comment: Une version française de StackOverflow a déjà été proposée sur Area51 mais, et c'est aussi le cas pour d'autres langues, la question a été supprimée par l'équipe StackExchange avec comme explication qu'il n'y avait pas assez de ressources pour gérer de nouvelles langues. Les seuls choix disponibles sont le [japonais](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/), le [portugais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), [l'espagnol](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) et le [russe](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/). Voir [cette question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299682/why-is-there-no-french-stack-overflow).

Comment: Voir aussi la question sur l'[_interface française_](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/530) du site. Par ailleurs, lors d'une recherche complétée il y a un moment, j'ai identifié le critère de la difficulté de compréhension (de l'anglais) des utilisateurs d'un groupe linguistique comme étant vecteur du développement de sites pour ces utilisateurs dans leur langue. De tels utilisateurs ne peuvent faire diminuer la fréquentation des sites de langue anglaise. Les francophones de France (en général et non pas ceux qui fréquentent le site) sont peu bilingues malgré des progrès...