# Faut-il le motif de clôture « question trop élémentaire » ? Do we want a “general reference” close reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Notre [site frère anglophone](https://english.stackexchange.com/) a un motif supplémentaire pour clore une question : « consulter un ouvrage de référence ».

> Cette question est trop élémentaire. On peut y répondre de manière complètement satisfaisante par un simple lien vers un site Internet qui fait référence sur le sujet.

Voulons-nous d'un tel motif sur notre site ?

---

[English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) has a [general reference close reason](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/939/how-to-respond-to-dictionary-general-reference-questions):

> This question is too basic; it can be definitively and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information.

Should we have this close reason too?

Comment: J'ai un doute sur la traduction du titre de cette question : est-ce que "trop élémentaire" veut vraiment dire la même chose que "general reference" ?

Comment: I think that this fear of too easy questions is unfounded. It is much more work to type an SE question asking for "What is the French word for dog?" than to type "dog" into a dictionary. On the German SE site this has not been a problem.

Comment: @BrennanVincent C'est un exemple de traduction non litérale. [Je suis ouvert à de meilleures propositions.](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/109/comment-traduire-general-reference-question)

Comment: Nous avons maintenant un [motif de clôture particulier](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/a/460). / We now have a [custom close reason](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/a/460).

Answer (score 7):

Oui. Ce site n'a pas vocation à remplacer un dictionnaire monolingue ou bilingue, ni une encyclopédie. Si une question trouve facilement sa réponse dans un ouvrage courant de ce type, elle doit être close.

Un site grevé de questions élémentaires n'a d'intérêt ni pour les débutants (qui auraient plus vite fait de consulter un dictionnaire), ni pour les francophones confirmés (qui ne sont pas intéressés par des questions et des réponses qu'ils trouvent évidentes).

---

Yes. This site should not try to replace a monolingual or bilingual dictionary or an encyclopedia. If a question is easily answered by looking it up in such a general reference, it should be closed.

A site full of elementary questions is not interesting to anyone, neither to beginners (who could get a faster answer from a dictionary) nor to native speakers (who are not interested in questions and answers that they find obvious).

Answer (score 5):

In that case, the voting system should be efficient enough, let votes decide of the relevance of the questions, as it was meant to.

---

Le système de vote est là pour traiter ce genre de problèmes, il est inutile, voire dangereux, de laisser les modérateurs seuls juges de la pertinence d'une question.

Comment: Au contraire, c'est le rôle des modérateurs. Je vois que tu n'es pas sur SE depuis très longtemps. Au bout de quelques mois, tu te rendras compte que le fait qu'une question ait un score élevé ne veut pas du tout dire que c'est une bonne question.

Comment: Au passage: cette semaine (pendant la bêta privée), tout le monde peut voter pour fermer une question. Après, il faudra un minimum de réputation.

Comment: Dans ce cas, à quoi sert le système de votes? "This question shows research efforts, it is clear and useful", ça me paraît exactement vouloir dire "bonne question".

Comment: Tant qu'une question reste ouverte, on peut y répondre. Clore une question, c'est un moyen de dire qu'on ne veut pas de la question sur le site. Il est très rare qu'une question reste ouverte avec un score négatif. Les deux mécanismes sont effectivement en partie redondant. Si tu penses qu'une question n'a pas sa place sur le site, vote pour la fermer.

Comment: Je sais, mais il suffit du jugement de cinq personnes, peu importe le consensus pour faire fermer une question, qui devient alors peu évidente à rouvrir. Le système de vote permet de juger en positif, au contraire du vote de clôture qui est plus un droit de veto. Je pense que les votes de clôture sont à réserver aux hors-sujets notoires, au spam et autres inappropriés et aux doublons. Dès que la pertinence est discutable, ce n'est pas le bon outil.

Comment: : encore une fois, ce débat a déjà amplement eu lieu sur Stack Exchange, et l'expérience montre que le système actuel marche bien. Il faut un vote de 5 personnes pour clore une question. En cas de contestation, on peut voter pour réouvrir (ça arrive rarement tout seul), ou en discuter sur le site meta et demander à un modérateur d'intervenir.

Comment: Je n'ai pas dit que le système de votes clôture était mauvais en soi, simplement qu'il n'est pas approprié dans ce cas. En ce qui concerne StackOverflow, pour prendre le plus populaire, "question trop élémentaire" n'a jamais été un motif de clôture valide, simplement un motif de vote négatif. C.f. infobulle sur le bouton de vote négatif "This question does not show any research effort [...]", sur SO comme ici.

Answer (score 3):

The "General Reference" close reason is being rolled out on [a very limited basis](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/939/how-to-respond-to-dictionary-general-reference-questions/1004#1004).

Currently, the General Reference closure is only being added *as-needed* to sites which have shown to be a problem.

In the meantime, you should still follow the *tenets* of the "General Reference" close reason:

> This question is too basic; it can be definitively and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information.

Those questions can be closed as [off topic], preferably with a comment explaining the policy.

Answer (score 1):

J'ai voté pour la [fermeture d'une question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1573/quelle-est-la-definition-de-avoir-un-faible-pour) mais aucun des choix de vote proposé ne correspondait au motif. Voir réponse de [Gilles](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5/gilles) Aug 17 at 22:08 ci-dessus.

L'usage nous montre qu'il faudrait avoir le choix de cocher *Cette question est trop élémentaire ; il suffit de consulter un dictionnaire pour pouvoir y répondre*.
Je soutiens l'intitulé **Question trop élémentaire**.

---

I voted to [close a question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1573/quelle-est-la-definition-de-avoir-un-faible-pour) but none of the proposed closure options was appropriate. [Gilles](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5/gilles) raised the problem on Aug 17 at 22:08 above.

Experience shows that we should be able to have the choice of [General Reference Question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/939/how-to-respond-to-dictionary-general-reference-questions) on French Language & Usage.

*Question trop élémentaire* seems a good title.