# Les réponses aux questions triviales ont-elles leur place sur notre site ? — Should French Language cover basic questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

J'ai très régulièrement des questions concernant l‘utilisation basique des règles de grammaire, d’orthographe, d’utilisation d'expressions, etc. Ce sont des questions triviales, mais que tout utilisateur de la langue française se pose à un moment ou à un autre. Par exemple un accord du participe passé avec l'auxiliaire avoir.

Étant adepte des sites Stack Exchange c'est donc l'endroit où je cherche en priorité. Malheureusement le site [*French Language*](https://french.stackexchange.com/) n'a pas (encore) réponse à tout, et je dois très régulièrement me tourner vers mon pote Google qui, en général, redirige vers la bonne réponse.

*French Language* est en bêta, l'objectif actuel est-il de couvrir le plus de questions pertinentes possibles afin d'améliorer son référencement et attirer plus de personnes ayant des questions à poser ([les statistiques sont un peu faible au niveau des questions/jours](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29480/french-language-usage)) ?

Dans ce cas, *French Language* ne devrait-il pas avoir lui aussi réponse à ces questions triviales (sans pour autant tomber dans l'excès de proposer des tables de conjugaison) ?

Si oui, cela implique-t-il d'encourager les personnes ayant ce type de questions à poster sur ce présent site Q&A alors qu'on sait très bien trouver la réponse ailleurs ?

---

I regularly have questions about the basics of grammar, orthographe, idioms, … They’re basic questions, but also questions that every French speaker asks oneself from time to time. How to agree a *participe passé* with the *avoir* auxiliary, e.g.

As an aficionado of Stack Exchange websites, I naturally search for my answers here first. Unfortunately, the [*French Language Stack Exchange*](https://french.stackexchange.com/) doesn’t have an answer for everything (yet). I thus often have to resort to Googling, which usually provides a correct answer.

*French Language* still is in beta. Is its current goal to provide answers to as many relevant questions as possible in order to improve search engine ranking and get more visitors with questions ? [The questions/day stats are a little low](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29480/french-language-usage) right now.

If it is the case, shouldn’t *French Language* provide answers to those basic questions (which doesn’t mean it should go over the top and offer conjugation tables)?

Should people with such questions be encouraged to ask them on this website, even though their answers could very well be found some place else?

Comment: L’accord du participe passé est une question triviale ? Vraiment ?

Comment: Triviale dans le sens où des centaines de site proposent déjà des explication avec exercices et exemples à la pelle sur ce sujet.

Comment: Je me suis permis de proposer une traduction.

Answer (score 6):

Le niveau d'un site n'a pas tendance à monter avec le temps, au contraire. Durant la bêta, il est important de maintenir un niveau de qualité égal ou supérieur à ce que l'on attend.

Le chiffre du nombre de questions n'est pas le seul critère qui fait la popularité et l'intérêt du site. Si le site ne fait que reprendre des informations que l'on trouve partout ailleurs, il sera noyé dans la masse.

Chaque question sur Stack Exchange demande un effort de la part des gens qui écrivent des réponses et fait du volume supplémentaire dans les recherches. C'est un coût qui est contrebalancé par l'intérêt des réponses. Si les réponses existent déjà et sont faciles à trouver (notamment dans un dictionnaire), le fait de les poser sur le site n'apporte aucun bénéfice qui compenserait ce coût.

Voir aussi des discussions passées sur le même thème :

- [Faut-il le motif de clôture « question trop élémentaire » ? Do we want a “general reference” close reason?](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20/faut-il-le-motif-de-cloture-question-trop-elementaire-do-we-want-a-genera)
- [What exactly are the "easy questions" that should be avoided?](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35/what-exactly-are-the-easy-questions-that-should-be-avoided)

Nous avons un [motif de clôture](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/why-havent-we-rolled-out-custom-close-reasons/460#460) pour les questions qui demandent le sens d'un mot ou d'une expression sans chercher plus loin qu'une définition de dictionnaire (par opposition à « que veut dire ce mot dans cette phrase, le dictionnaire ne m'a pas aidé », qui est exactement le genre de questions que Stack Exchange cherche à couvrir).

Comment: Ok, merci pour les précisions sur les objectifs de FL&U (récemment renommé d'ailleurs ?). D'ailleurs ces objectifs ne devraient-ils pas être plus visible ?

Comment: @Fractaliste On trouve ces objectifs résumés sur la page [à propos](http://french.stackexchange.com/about) et en plus de détails dans des messages sur le [blog officiel](http://blog.stackexchange.com/). Ce n'est effectivement pas forcément facile de trouver les points importants, et c'est à tempérer par le fait que ce que les fondateurs veulent n'est pas toujours exactement ce qui se passe.

Answer (score 5):

Je ne vois pas l'intérêt de poser des questions dont on peut avoir les réponses facilement ailleurs. Les questions basiques (plutôt que triviales) ont déjà leurs réponses dans des sites très bien faits, comme le [Point du FLE](http://www.lepointdufle.net/) par exemple, il y en a d'autres<sup>1</sup>.
Les sites de Stackexchange, me semble-t-il, ont pour vocation, sans s'adresser forcément à des spécialistes, de chercher à élever la discussion au-dessus du lot.  J'aurais envie de dire *StackExchange fills up the parts other sites do not reach*.<sup>2</sup>

<sup>1</sup> J'exclue Wordreference souvent cité sur *French Language* ici de cette liste.
<sup>2</sup>  Allusion à un slogan publicitaire bien connu des Anglais, et j'avoue ne pas savoir si la marque en question l'a adapté en français.

Comment: Pour pouvoir être amené à élever la discussion il faut que les gens aient le réflexe de les poser ici et non ailleurs. Et donc pour y arriver il faut travailler la visibilité du site. D'après vos réponses le consensus a l'air général de ne pas vouloir encourager les questions "basiques" et donc de ne pas booster le référencement. Merci pour les clarifications !