# Questions sur les expressions idiomatiques françaises

Tags: discussion, questions, question-quality

Est-ce que c'est une bonne idée de poser des questions sur les expressions idiomatiques française telles que « Avoir la puce à l'oreille » sur SE ? Je suis sûr qu'on peut trouver des sites entiers parlant du sujet et que la recherche ne prendrait pas beaucoup de temps, mais dans le but de faire grimper le site dans les résultats de recherche de google et donc attirer des nouveaux utilisateurs (et aussi pour le rendre  plus complet possible), est-ce que ce serait un genre de question à poser malgré tout ?

---

Would it be a good idea to ask questions about French idiomatic expressions? I'm sure one can quickly and easily find many sites on this topic. Nonetheless, in order to increase the site's visibility, and thereby attract new visitors — as well as to make the site cover as much material as possible — is this the kind of questions we should ask?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tant que la qualité des réponses est meilleure qu'ailleurs je ne vois pas pourquoi on devrait se priver de ces questions. J'aurais même tendance à les encourager.

*As long as the quality of the answers is better than elsewhere, I don't see why we should not have such questions. I would even tend to encourage them.*

Comment: +1 I totally agree! The fact that other sources exist doesn't mean that we can't do better.

Answer (score 5):

#### Poser une question dont on connaît la réponse

Poser une question dont on connaît la réponse n'est pas en soi une mauvaise idée, mais c'est plus délicat d'éviter de poser des questions inintéressantes. Si tu t'es posé une question, et que tu ne connaissais pas la réponse avant d'avoir fait un peu de recherche, c'est une bonne idée de poser la question ici et d'y répondre toi-même.

En revanche, il vaut mieux éviter de poser une question juste pour le plaisir. En particulier, j'incite les locuteurs natifs à ne pas poser de questions de la forme « que veut dire l'expression X » (sauf à ne pas en connaître le sens, bien sûr) : il est difficile de savoir si ces questions seront intéressantes pour autrui.

Une exception dans l'exception : si la question ne vient pas (que) de toi, par exemple si tu es professeur de français et que tu as l'habitude que tes élèves aient du mal sur un point particulier, c'est une bonne idée de le faire apparaître ici (sous forme de question-réponse).

#### Des questions sur le sens des expressions

Le sens de « avoir la puce à l'oreille » ne pose pas de difficulté particulière, donc ce n'est pas une question particulièrement intéressante même si elle est légitime. (Ce n'est pas toujours le cas, certains idiomes sont difficiles à cerner.) Il y a par contre souvent des questions auxiliaires intéressantes : quelle est son étymologie ? Comment le sens a-t-il évolué au cours du temps (l'histoire de « avoir la puce à l'oreille » a l'air assez tarabiscotée) ? Est-ce que l'expression a des [connotations différentes suivant les dialectes](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/177/is-there-a-non-religious-definition-of-catholique) ?

Ce genre de question est beaucoup plus utile si l'on fait un peu de recherche préliminaire avant de la poser. Cela permet d'orienter la question vers les aspects qui ne sont pas traités convenablement par les premiers résultats d'une recherche Google. Ainsi la question invite des réponses qui vont au-delà de ce que peuvent offrir les sites existants, et contribue à faire de ce site une référence qui sort du lot.

---

#### On asking questions where you know the answer

*Summary:* there's nothing wrong with asking a question if you already know the answer, but this should represent something that wasn't obvious to you, that required research.

#### On questions about the meaning of expressions

The meaning of “*avoir la puce à l'oreille*” is easy to understand, so asking about it is not so interesting. (This isn't always the case; some idioms are tricky to figure out.) There are, however, often interesting side questions: what is the etymology of this expression? How did it evolve over time (this particular specimen seems to have had a convoluted history)? Does it have [different connotations in different dialects](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/177/is-there-a-non-religious-definition-of-catholique)?

These questions will work best if you do a bit of research before asking and steer the question towards aspects that are not well-covered by the top Google results. This pushes towards answers that go beyond what existing sites can do — in other words, if you ask a difficult question, you're more likely to get an answer that can be the reference on the web.

Answer (score 2):

Comme je l'ai déjà dit pour [Faut-il le motif de clôture « question trop élémentaire » ? Do we want a “general reference” close reason?](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20/faut-il-le-motif-de-cloture-question-trop-elementaire-do-we-want-a-general/23#23) si une question reçoit un score positif et qu'elle est en rapport avec le français c'était une bonne idée de la poser.

*As I've said [before](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20/faut-il-le-motif-de-cloture-question-trop-elementaire-do-we-want-a-general/23#23), if a question has a positive score and is about the French language then it was a good idea to ask it.*

Comment: Experience on Stack Exchange shows that a lot of upvotes on a question is not a sign that the question is worth keeping.

Comment: @Gilles: Bof. Define *worth keeping*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes, …

Comment: @Gilles : Only it's a lot easier to get a lot of upvotes on bigger non-beta sites, so I wouldn't worry about that, at least [for now](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/245/taking-stock-are-we-losing-steam-is-our-identity-coalescing?rq=1). (I guess "Define *a lot*" would be another version of this comment.)

Answer (score 1):

I would be very interested to know where "la puce à l'oreille" comes from, and was kinda deceived to see the question wasn't actually asked but was used as a meta excuse.

So please go ahead and post it for real, since now I'm too lazy to search for an answer myself.

As you can see, in a nutshell, I agree with what the others said.

Answer (score 0):

On peut trouver beaucoup de choses sur internet, certes. Mais on peut aussi trouver des choses **dans des livres, dictionnaires spécialisés, etc**. Certains visiteurs peuvent avoir des accès à des livres que d'autres n'ont pas et apporter des compléments intéressants.