# Traduction de la nouvelle page d'accueil / French version of the new about page

Tags: discussion, about-page

Je viens d'éditer le chapeau de la nouvelle page d'accueil, [`https://french.stackexchange.com/about`](https://french.stackexchange.com/about), de manière à inclure une version française. Merci d'utiliser cette discussion pour toutes remarques et suggestions d'amélioration, que les modérateurs pourront intégrer à la page.

---

I've added a French version of the welcome text on [`https://french.stackexchange.com/about`](https://french.stackexchange.com/about). I'm opening the discussion here about what its content should be.

Comment: Éditer le chapeau de la nouvelle page?  You mean the "header"?  :-)

Comment: @Jez oui, le [chapeau](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chapeau): « 1907 arg. des journalistes *“texte court qui précède un article, un livre”* (France) » (je pense même que le terme est désormais passé au langage courant)

Answer (score 2):

En gros : Excellent :·)

En petit :

- Il fait parti**e** de la famille …
- La forme « questions–réponses » me surprend un peu. Au moins, je raccourcirais le tiret (en [trait d'union](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiret#Tiret_court)), à défaut de le remplacer par un slash (→ « questions/réponses »).
- Je ne pense pas que *post-scriptum*¹ mérite de piquer sa majuscule à « l'interface » (→ « PS : L'interface … »).
- Je laisserais *par vous* en italique, comme dans l'original (plutôt que seulement *vous*), parce que ça se voit mieux (et c'est assez neutre sémantiquement).
- Je discuterais *de ∅ langue française*, ou bien *à propos de la langue française*, mais c'est peut-être juste moi (plutôt que de *discuter de la langue française*).

---

¹ Qui s'il n'en tenait qu'à moi s'abrévierait « P.-S. », mais peu importe.

Comment: 1. Bien sûr. 2. Le en-dash est parfait, il est fait pour ça. 3. D'accord. 4. À l'oral c'est bien le *vous* qui serait accentué. 5. Ce n'est que toi :-) P.-S.: s'il n'en tenait qu'à moi aussi.

Answer (score 0):

Comment est-ce que cette page "à propos" se rapporte à la section FAQ?  Est-il prévu de la remplacer ou de la compléter?

J'ai noté que la FAQ actuelle ne correspond pas à ce que nous avons [décidé](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/translation-questions-questions-de-traduction) à propos des traductions, parce qu'elle les décourage trop ("We are not a translation service, nor do we purport to be experts in languages other than French.").

---

How does this about page relate to the FAQ section?  Is it intended to replace it or complement it?

I've noticed that the existing FAQ doesn't really correspond to what we decided about [translations](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/translation-questions-questions-de-traduction), because it discourages them too much ("We are not a translation service, nor do we purport to be experts in languages other than French.")

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163254/142977

Comment: Hmm, that discussion seems to suggest that the about page will be in addition to the FAQ, though it doesn't completely confirm it.

Comment: yeah, FAQ and about page should coexist. The about page is more about the mechanisms and user interface of the site (rather generic), while the FAQ details the policies…

Comment: Comment @Jez: FAQ is often compatibly translated as “Foire aux questions” and is therefore used with a feminine gender in French.

Answer (score -1):

A suggestion (with the aim of remaining close to the original).  Pick whatever parts you find appropriate:

> *French Language and Usage* est un site de questions–réponses destiné aux étudiants, aux enseignants et linguistes, souhaitant discuter des points les plus délicats de la langue française. Il fait partie du réseau *Stack Exchange*, c'est donc *vous* qui le construisez et le faites vivre. Grâce à votre aide, nous nous donnons pour but de réunir un large inventaire de réponses, détaillées, aux questions concernant le français.
>
> P.-S. L'interface du site, ainsi que le reste de la présentation ci-dessous, sont pour l'instant uniquement en anglais. Nous en sommes désolés !